# oracle 11g express edition data can't be found or inserted using DataGrip

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datagrip

I'm making a database with Oracle 11g Express Edition, and I have two problems.

1. I've added many insert queries to populate my database in the oracle command line. but then after, when I connect the database to the DataGrip I can't find any rows even though the command line is still opened.
   [rows created using SQL command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCMqb.png)

[no data found in DataGrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYUwu.png)

2. now even if I execute some insert queries, they won't be executed, I will just wait uselessly.
   [Datagrip insert queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2DhA.png)

Comment: It says that you requested cancelling. You did not?

Comment: I did, but because I know it won't execute, I waited like for 10 minutes and it's still executing.

Comment: did you commit after the inserts? No commit means no other session will see those rows, but they would block other sessions if they keys overlapped

Comment: thank you so much Sir, It worked. I really appreciate it, you made me so excited. have a great day!

Comment: Make sure you've committed the transaction you're working in. By the way, what's your transaction isolation level?